# Is $Z_2(G)$ abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-groups

Let $G$ be non-abelian finite p-group and Let $\frac{Z_2(G)}{Z(G)}$ be elementary abelian group
how we can get $Z_2(G)$ is abelian?
If it's needed we also know $|Z(G)|=p$ and $|Z_2(G)|=p^3$

Comment: Is $|Z_2(G)|=3$ or $|Z_2(G)|=p^3$? What is $\frac{Z_2(G)}{Z(G)}$ be elementary abelian group?

Comment: How is $Z_n(G)$ defined?

Comment: it is defined in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_series)

Comment: Take $G$ to be the set of upper triangular unipotent matrices in $GL_3(F_p)$. Then $G=Z_2(G)$ is non-abelian of order $p^3$, while $Z(G)$ is of order $p$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Why not ? It is finite, and a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $GL(3,p)$, isn't it ?